A virus/trojan/easter egg in iOS simulator?
iOS simulator out of the blue asked for permission to control another process
and all of a sudden I got it playing annoying boat like sounds from a speaker.
Any ideas how to remove that permission or reinstall the thing altogether?
The Xcode is 15.4 the simulator was for iOS 17.2 in case it matters and all
versions of Xcode were downloaded from apple website. Or so I hope.
Maybe I can somehow verify the checksums of the perpetrator?
Not sure how to get out of this predicament. I could not attach audio on s.o. sites or could I?

You should consider installing Xcode from the Mac App Store. If you are looking at installing an older version of Xcode, make sure to only download from https://developer.apple.com/downloads

It turned out UI tests were running and there was a noisy feedback alerting to the simulated user input. Given that I never saw UI tests in a previous projects I was startled.
